# Detect when ALL HTML page rendering has taken place

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, dom, xhtml

I am working with a pretty complicated .aspx page that is full of controls (Telerik, Ajax, etc.) that all expand, collapse, show, hide, etc. when the page is loaded.  Since this rendering happens on the client-side and can take different lengths of time based on the users machine specs, is there a way to detect when all (or some) rendering has taken place (jQuery?) so I can then act on specific elements, knowing they are fully rendered?

Comment: As you are the one adding these onload actions - why don't you add a trigger at the end of the actions? or maybe add some "polling" of an item that changes during onload?

Comment: do you need something after the `document.ready()` moment?

Comment: "Rendered" may be a bit ambiguous here. Do you want to know when all the page elements have completed *animating* (for lack of a better term)? That is, do you want to know when the stuff that's supposed to be expanded is expanded, the stuff that's supposed to be hidden is hidden, etc.?

Comment: @Jeff - I do mean animating unfortunately, hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded. The time passed to `setTimeout` is a minimum, but not a maximum, so if you pass something like 10(ms), you essentially are saying "execute this code after all the currently running code is finished."

So, if all the controls use `$(document).ready()` to do their thing, all you need is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        doStuff();
    },10);
});
```

`doStuff` will be called after all the functions passed to `$(document).ready` have run. However, this isn't foolproof. If the controls have their own way of detecting whether the document has loaded, or do their own `setTimeout()`, you're in trouble. The problem is that JavaScript does not guarantee the execution order of `setTimeout`s. Sometimes your code may run last, other times it may run before the `setTimeout`s used for the animation.

One last idea: if all the animation is done using jQuery, then the effects run in a single queue. In `doStuff` you could add an animation of some sort [with a callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsoptions) and be reasonably certain that the callback would run last.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I had to wait for multiple things to be ready before proceeding, I would create an array with true/false values. Every mandatory part of the page got an event which, when it is called, updates the specific entry in the array to true. Also, it called a general function which returned true if all values in an array was true, otherwise false.

If that function finally returned true, I would proceed with the execution. It is especially useful if you have to wait for an AJAX call to end but don't want to use async = true. It also is useful if you want to start loading multiple things at once instead of one after another, since they all report ready-state to the same array.

It does however use global variables so you might need to do some optimizations. You might not want to do this approach either if you have a grudge against global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your code inside the jQuery $(document).ready() function. This will ensure that all elements are loaded before the code runs.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: .ready executes whenever the DOM is ready, not if the rendering is finished! If you want to wait for the page to finish rendering, then you need .load.

Answer (score 0):

I think the doc you need is:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/load

Answer (score 0):

"I can then act on specific elements, knowing they are fully rendered?"

You can use the load method (linked above) to attach to any element. So if you had a div with an id of "lastElement", you could write

```
$('div#lastElement).load(runThisFunction);
```